# CSS :visited border change

Tags: css

Well, what I did is I styled the a elements to look like this

[image]

Thing is, when that link is visited it gets some sort of black solid border instead of the outset/inset borders.
[image]

PS: I tried using the :visited selector and sett the border but that didn't work.

Here's what I use in HTML:

```
<a href ='link' class='button'>Editer</a>
```

CSS:

```
.button {
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#000000;
    padding:1px;
    padding-left:5px;
    padding-right:5px;
    background:url(../image/admin/cp_button_bg.gif);
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:12px;
    border:outset;
}
.button:active {
    border:inset;
}
.button:visited {
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

Comment: [**Links Are Not Buttons**](http://www.karlgroves.com/2013/05/14/links-are-not-buttons-neither-are-divs-and-spans/) We need to see this in action.

Comment: @Paulie_D how do you hyperlink something in the comments?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:visited visited doesn't work without an a tag. It needs a pointer to an adress. In an a tag: the href attribute.

Comment: exactly @ Paulie_D @CosX I'm using <a></a> tag

Comment: Like this \[Link text here\]\(hyper link in here\)

Comment: `.button { outline: 0 }`

Comment: `border:outset` or `inset` is not valid AFAIK...

Comment: Fixed this by changing the border-color when visited

Comment: It's not a valid property for border...it is for `outline` though, All borders are outside the element.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed this by changing the border-color when :visited

Answer (score 0):

try using

```
.button:visited {
    border:none;
}
```

or

```
.button:visited {
    border:outset;
}
```